# how transfer function from template class

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <functional>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class someclass {
public:
    T value;
    int sum(int vl1, int vl2) { return vl1 + vl2; };
};

template <typename T>
class someclass2 {
public:
    T value; 
    void print(const std::function<int(int, int)>& func) {
        cout << func(3, 4) << '\n';
    };
};

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    someclass<int> obj1;
    someclass2<int> obj2;
    obj2.print(obj1.sum); 
}
```

Compiler show error on last line : error C3867: 'someclass::sum': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Comment: Long story short, you should use `&someclass::sum` **and** make `sum` a `static` member function.

Comment: @nm or call it with a lambda, or use `std::bind`

Comment: ok. ty for answer.  is there other ways to do same?

Comment: @MykhailoOgorodniichuk Same **what**?

Comment: Alternatively you can use `std::bind(obj1, &someclass::sum)` or a lambda (but both are unnecessary in this case because your `sum` doesn't use `this` in any way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

```
int sum(int vl1, int vl2) { return vl1 + vl2; };
```

doesn't use its owner class' member in any way, it safely can be declared static, in that case this code would work.

The problem with this code is that a member function got a different type from standalone function. It's a member of class `someclass`, so its type is `int (someclass::*)(int, int)` and to call it you need an instance of that class.

The literal solution in general case is to hide pass of `this` inside the functor created by lambda expression:

```
obj2.print( [&](int a, int b)-> int { return obj1.sum(a,b); } );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `std::bind` to do that

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    someclass<int> obj1;
    someclass2<int> obj2;

    using namespace std::placeholders;
    obj2.print(std::bind(&someclass<int>::sum, &obj1, _1, _2));
}
```

Comment: it`s funny. because i was sure i tried this and got error(and this is why i got this question), but now when i copy+paste  it work. something wrong with me probably. anyway ty for answer

Comment: @MykhailoOgorodniichuk bind is capricious in some implementations, especially if compiler is not fully standard. If you check russian stackoverflow, you'll find examples of that and a discussion.